# Laser engraver on Ender 3 without taking important ports

Tags: creality-ender-3, laser

I'm contemplating buying a laser engraver attachment for my Ender 3 Pro.  Either the Creality official one or the Comgrow version.

When scanning the [respective web pages](https://www.comgrow.com/products/20w-laser-engraver-module-kit-for-ender-3-3-pro-3v2?variant=39438266630187)/[answers on here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/convert-3d-printer-to-laser-engraver) and [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEk3aVARSGc), it seems like you usually unplug cables for fans and swap them with laser, etc.

**So I guess my question is**:  if I still wanted to be able to easily print, let's say within 10 mins of engraving something, without opening up my printer's electronics case to swap cables every time... what would be the best approach?

Is there a way to have everything permanently plugged in and the G-code file simply dictates what is done (3D printing vs lasering).

I have a different board than the default Creality if that changes anything (a BTT E3 RRF Board).  I also have the IDEX expansion board plugged in, that's currently only running a second Z-axis motor (i.e. probably has extra plugs on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to open the electronics casing, why not cut/split the (print) fan cable so that you can plug it quick without too much delay. The power for the laser could be fed directly from a power supply.

Comment: Just so I understand..... the cable from the board out to the fan would be split (once out of the box) and there would be a plug out there for the laser?  I would then plug in the laser to that whenever I needed it?   If its that easy....  I'm dumb.

Comment: I would cut it at the printhead, just before the cable goes into the fan and crimp on a female and male header on each end of the cable (take some extra length if possible), but I don't have an Ender to verify it that is possible. If you want the laser, disconnect the fan and plug in the laser in the fan socket near the print head. If you place the laser module onto the print head, beware of the offset in your slicer! Your effective area might be less than used for 3D printing.